# Azure service bus queue send messages error in azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-servicebus-queues

I am trying to send a message to a queue in service bus using the service bus explorer.The message type is json and I get the below error.

```
{
   "filepath": "/testing/myfolder/test.json",
   "parameters": {
        "one": "1"
        }
}
```

> Failed to send messages
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createSender')

[image]

This works fine in a dev resource group service bus.

Comment: Can you add a snapshot of the actual message you tried to send and the error from the portal?

Comment: @nobody are you using any code to send Azure service bus queue send messages test.json? if could you specify it

Comment: @Sampath No code, the message is pasted directly in the portal service bus explorer.Right next to Peek mode in service bus explorer for the queue, there is a "send messages" options that opens up a window where you can choose the message type and the message body.

Comment: @nobody 
``` {
    "filepath": "/testing/myfolder/test.json",
    "parameters": {
        "one": "1"
    }
}``` 
able to send this message in the Azure portal with message type JSON and [plaintext](https://i.imgur.com/P2ZVpmq.png). please check your respective network and resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out in DEV environment I have "owner" permissions to the service bus/queues whereas in PROD environment I only have "reader" permissions to the service bus/queues.